# Where should I specify the branch and changeset when deploying binaries with maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am trying to use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to deploy some binaries not related to java and I need to specify some information that would be critical for identifying the right artefact to download later:

- branch - as we do build different branches in parallel and is common for them to share the same version
- changeset(s) - these would uniquely identify a build and I need to be able to query maven to give me the binary for a specific changeset.

It would be nice if I could keep using the deploy-file plugin for that.

Note: I tried to check the documentation page at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html but it is not clear what would be the correct approach.

At this moment I am publishing builds using 1.0-SNAPSHOT but this only indicate the build time which is not ok.

Comment: Something in the version like `1.0-BranchName-ChangeSet` ?

Comment: I was considering the same pattern but i have some concerns regarding length limitation and use of special characters inside the branch name. if branch name has dashes inside, spaces,... think that many of this binaries are RPMs. I do like the idea of using the same pattern for nexus version and for rpm naming.

Comment: Length shouldn't be a problem. A branch name with spaces sounds weird...but dashes ok...But why do you need so strange branch names? May be you can elaborate a little bit more...

Answer (score 2):

An artifact in Maven is defined by:

- Group Id
- Artifact Id
- Packaging
- Classifier
- Version

Nothing else can be added on top of that. I think the best is to use a version number that also uses the GIT commit id (or something similar depending on what VCS you are using) when deploying the file. It should be trivial to trace back the changes done from the commit id.

Comment: Yeah, I normally use the [Classifier](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html) bit for these kinds of things.

Comment: So, at this moment it seems that we are going towards a pattern of using version=1.0-changeset and classifier=branchname (or maybe even none for master/trunk). I like this approach, the only concern is that if I will need to use classifiers for other reasons, I will not be able to because I am using them as branches.

Comment: Seems strange to use the classifier for this. The intention of classifier is to define artifacts that are related (like the normal jar, the sources jar, the test jar, etc..). I have also seen use of classifier to indicate certain java version compatibility (E.g. a jdk6 only version)

Comment: I am still hoping to get some feedback from someone that picked one solution and was successful in using it. I already have some issues with the usage of version=1.0-changset because it seems that would break the ability to get latest build for current branch. Maybe it would be better to use version=1.0-branch and classifiers=changeset